# Create sequence in R by time difference and duplicate

Tags: r

Good evening, I have a question for a passage in R. I have this dataframe in which camera trap FT, date and time (DATAORA) and the time difference (in seconds) between occasions (DIFFTIME) are specified.

Dataframe:

```
input <- structure(list(FT = structure(c(4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 1L), levels = c("T1", "C1a", "C1b", "C1c", "T2", "C2b", "C2c", 
"T3", "C3a", "C3b", "T4", "C4a", "C4b", "C4c", "T5", "C5a", "C5b", 
"C5c", "T6", "C6a", "C6b", "C6c", "T7", "C7a", "C7b", "C7c", 
"T8", "C8a", "C8b", "C8c", "T9", "C9a", "C9b", "C9c", "T10", 
"C10a", "C10b", "C10c", "T11", "C11a", "C11b", "C11c", "T12", 
"C12a"), class = "factor"), DATAORA = structure(c(1668717618, 
1668717644, 1668717750, 1668717790, 1668717806, 1668719092, 1668719110, 
1668719142, 1668719156, 1668719182, 1668719192, 1668719214, 1668800778, 
1668800808, 1668800832, 1668800846, 1668800856, 1668800860, 1668800872, 
1668800888, 1668800898, 1668800926, 1668809108, 1668809170, 1668809226, 
1668809238), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), DIFFTIME = c(0, 
26, 106, 40, 16, 1286, 18, 32, 14, 26, 10, 22, 81564, 30, 24, 
14, 10, 4, 12, 16, 10, 28, 8182, 62, 56, 12)), row.names = c(NA, 
-26L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to create a column in which are specified the groups/sequences identified from the rows of the dataframe. I would like these groups/sequences to be specified by grouping rows that do not differ by more than 45 seconds and yet when a row has a duplicate of FT then insert it into the next group. As follows

Expected result:

```
expected <- structure(list(FT = c("C1c", "C1c", "T1", "C1a", "T1", "C1c", 
"C1b", "C1b", "T1", "T1", "C1a", "T1", "C1b", "C1b", "C1a", "T1", 
"C1b", "C1a", "T1", "C1a", "T1", "T1", "C1c", "C1b", "C1a", "T1"
), DATAORA = c("2022-11-17 21:40:18", "2022-11-17 21:40:44", 
"2022-11-17 21:42:30", "2022-11-17 21:43:10", "2022-11-17 21:43:26", 
"2022-11-17 22:04:52", "2022-11-17 22:05:10", "2022-11-17 22:05:42", 
"2022-11-17 22:05:56", "2022-11-17 22:06:22", "2022-11-17 22:06:32", 
"2022-11-17 22:06:54", "2022-11-18 20:46:18", "2022-11-18 20:46:48", 
"2022-11-18 20:47:12", "2022-11-18 20:47:26", "2022-11-18 20:47:36", 
"2022-11-18 20:47:40", "2022-11-18 20:47:52", "2022-11-18 20:48:08", 
"2022-11-18 20:48:18", "2022-11-18 20:48:46", "2022-11-18 23:05:08", 
"2022-11-18 23:06:10", "2022-11-18 23:07:06", "2022-11-18 23:07:18"
), DIFFTIME = c(0, 26, 106, 40, 16, 1286, 18, 32, 14, 26, 10, 
22, 81564, 30, 24, 14, 10, 4, 12, 16, 10, 28, 8182, 62, 56, 12
), SEQ = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 16)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -26L))
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Is there a reason you deleted the first version of your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77748104/create-sequence-in-r-by-time-difference-and-duplicate

Comment: Because there was an answer from a certain Jon, but it disappeared and I thought the problem was in my question

Comment: @Isac97 One question for clarification - when you mention "duplicate of FT" did you mean when the FT changes from one row to the next? For example, rows 7 and 8 have the same FT? Or did you mean if FT is duplicated at any time, for example, T1 in rows 3, 5, 9, and 10?

Comment: @Ben The first one. Basically when I have two or more rows that are no more than 45 seconds apart I can consider them the same sequence, but if one of these contains a duplicate then from that on I open a new sequence. At this point, however, for each duplicate I don't open a new sequence, I create a new sequence and if within that or duplicates I open the next one (always with respect to the current sequence, not the previous one). I do not know if I was clear.

Comment: @Ben I essentially have 4 slots to fill for each sequence: T1, C1a, C1b and C1c. But if the lines are more than 45 seconds apart or I encounter a duplicate I open a new sequence. It doesn't matter whether the previous one has filled the slots or not

Comment: @Isac97 To clarify further - I see that SEQ 6 (rows 8 and 9) have DIFFTIMEs of 32 and 14. I see it is a new SEQ since the FT is the same as in row 7 (C1b)...but the cumulative time is 32 + 14 = 46...shouldn't row 9 start a new sequence then and have SEQ of 7? Or are you ignoring DIFFTIME when a new sequence is started?

Comment: @Ben No, I'm only interested in ensuring that the individual rows are no more than 45 seconds apart. If line 9 had a DIFFTIME of 46 then a new sequence began (7). In short, DIFFTIME is not cumulative.

Comment: @Isac97 Still trying to understand...if line 5 has DIFFTIME of 16 sec, that is still <45 but there is a new SEQ of 4 for that row...the FT is T1 which is different than the row above it (C1a) - why would row 5 have a new SEQ? It might help to write out the logic to explain why the SEQ increases for a few example rows...

Comment: @Ben All right.
- row 1 C1c SEQ 1, 
- row 2 C1c is a duplicate compared to the previous sequence therefore SEQ 2,
- row 3 is 106 seconds from 2 so a new sequence begins (SEQ 3), row 4 has an FT which is not duplicated because in SEQ 3 there is only T1 and now there is C1a, therefore always SEQ 3
- row 5 there is a duplicate because there is T1 again so it is assigned to a new sequence (SEQ 4). It doesn't matter if it is not duplicated compared to row 4, it is a duplicate because in sequence 3 T1 has already been occupied (as a slot) by row 3,

Comment: @Ben - row 6 distance greater than 45 seconds therefore new sequence (SEQ 5), row 7 always sequence 5 because it is less than 45 seconds away and is not duplicated,
- row 8 there is C1b which has already been occupied (as a slot) by row 7, therefore new sequence (SEQ 6), row 9 is less than 45 seconds away and is not duplicated, therefore always SEQ 6
- row 7 there is T1 which has already been occupied (as a slot) in the previous sequence therefore new SEQ 7...etc

Comment: @Ben - row 14 C1b has already been occupied (as a slot) in the previous sequence therefore new sequence (SEQ 10), row 15 and row 16 are less than 45 seconds apart therefore always SEQ 10,
- row 17 C1b has already been occupied in the previous sequence therefore new sequence SEQ 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to try out - if helpful, I can edit and clarify more details about this works. You can use `input` instead of `expected` for data source, but I just created a new column `new_seq` to compare with `SEQ` to ensure they are the same.

Starting with sequence 1 `seq_no` you can go through each row of data separately. With each row you can evaluate if the `FT` is contained within the currently active `SEQ` group, and if the `DIFFTIME` exceeds 45 seconds. If either is true, then you can advance to the next sequence number `seq_no`, and reset the currently active group to only contain that `FT`. If both are false, then just add that `FT` to the current group. The final statement stores the sequence number in the proper row.

```
seq_no <- 1
current_grp <- vector()

for(i in seq_len(nrow(expected))) {
  if (expected[i, "FT"] %in% current_grp | expected[i, "DIFFTIME"] > 45) {
    seq_no <- seq_no + 1
    current_grp <- expected[i, "FT"]
  } else {
    current_grp <- c(current_grp, expected[i, "FT"])
  }
  expected[i, "new_seq"] <- seq_no
}

expected
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 26 × 5
   FT    DATAORA             DIFFTIME   SEQ new_seq
   <chr> <chr>                  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 C1c   2022-11-17 21:40:18        0     1       1
 2 C1c   2022-11-17 21:40:44       26     2       2
 3 T1    2022-11-17 21:42:30      106     3       3
 4 C1a   2022-11-17 21:43:10       40     3       3
 5 T1    2022-11-17 21:43:26       16     4       4
 6 C1c   2022-11-17 22:04:52     1286     5       5
 7 C1b   2022-11-17 22:05:10       18     5       5
 8 C1b   2022-11-17 22:05:42       32     6       6
 9 T1    2022-11-17 22:05:56       14     6       6
10 T1    2022-11-17 22:06:22       26     7       7
11 C1a   2022-11-17 22:06:32       10     7       7
12 T1    2022-11-17 22:06:54       22     8       8
13 C1b   2022-11-18 20:46:18    81564     9       9
14 C1b   2022-11-18 20:46:48       30    10      10
15 C1a   2022-11-18 20:47:12       24    10      10
16 T1    2022-11-18 20:47:26       14    10      10
17 C1b   2022-11-18 20:47:36       10    11      11
18 C1a   2022-11-18 20:47:40        4    11      11
19 T1    2022-11-18 20:47:52       12    11      11
20 C1a   2022-11-18 20:48:08       16    12      12
21 T1    2022-11-18 20:48:18       10    12      12
22 T1    2022-11-18 20:48:46       28    13      13
23 C1c   2022-11-18 23:05:08     8182    14      14
24 C1b   2022-11-18 23:06:10       62    15      15
25 C1a   2022-11-18 23:07:06       56    16      16
26 T1    2022-11-18 23:07:18       12    16      16
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much! It works perfectly! I also tested it on the entire database and it's excellent! Thank you so much! I understood more or less how the problem was approached, an explanation would help me even more. Obviously when you have time, for now thank you very much! Very kind!

Comment: The explanation has now arrived, thank you very much!